# Glut/OpenGL always renders black window

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, intel, glut

I am changing the window background color using the Glut library, which isn't working. The code works perfectly on my peer's computers but not on mine. I am using Visual Studio on Windows 10, with intel i5,8th gen, with integrated graphics.

I searched on Reddit threads, and the only thing relevant was that integrated graphics may be the issue.

Is integrated graphics really the issue or something else?

Are there any solutions to this problem, except changing the graphic cards?

Note- The library should be OpenGL, glut, glu only...

Code:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <gl/GLU.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void draw() {}
void display() {
  glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  gluOrtho2D(0, 640, 0, 480);
  // draw();
  glFlush();
  return;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_SINGLE);
  glutInitWindowPosition(200, 200);
  glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
  glutCreateWindow("House");
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutMainLoop();
  return 0;
}
```

I tried this code, and although it renders a window, it is black in color, which it should not be. It should be (as the question) any random color. Are there any solutions i can try?

Comment: *"The code works perfectly on my peers' computers but not on mine."* - So it's obviously not a problem with the code.

Comment: @Rabbid76 usually that is a problem with the code

Comment: @user253751 No, the code is fine. I have tested it.

Comment: The code shows a yellow background on my machine (Intel HD 630). The code looks fine to me.

Comment: Which GLUT implementation are you using?  FreeGLUT?  Terrifyingly old Nate Robins' GLUT?  Also, try `GLUT_SINGLE` -> `GLUT_DOUBLE` & `glFlush()` -> `glutSwapBuffers()`.

Comment: Are you sure you only get an RGB context as requested (with `GLUT_RGB`)? If you also get an alpha channel then I've seen some drivers do strange things with alpha values other than 1.0 in the clear colour. Might be worth trying `glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)`. Just guessing though.